# How to map data from AutoQuotes Catalog Data Export to Magento Standard Products File to Import?

Tags: admin, import, magento-1.9

I am creating an e-commerce website using Magento 1.9 platform and they ask me to take the products data from AutoQuotes Catalog Data Export (http://aqnet.com, and they provide a Windows application with authentication to access the user's database).

However, the CSV file which is downloaded from the software has many columns which does not appear in a standard Import File of Magento (and vice-versa). I just want to ask what is the best way to map those data because there are approximately more than 10,000 products or what is the best solution I can do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few extensions that you could use to build your own import on top of the standard Magento import process.

1. [Fast Simple Import](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport)
2. [HO Import](https://github.com/ho-nl/Ho_Import)

There is also a few good blog posts about import.

1. http://www.integer-net.com/2012/04/04/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/
2. http://www.integer-net.com/2014/05/27/product-import-with-magento/

But I would suggest that you may have to build your own mapping between Magento and this new csv. In this case one of the extensions mentioned should help you out.